# If $f\in C^2(I)$, and $f''>0$, then $f$ is concave up.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I proved the first part of the following question. Can you help me with the second part?

Suppose a real-valued function $f$ is twice continuously differentiable in
an open neighborhood $I$ of the point $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

1. Prove that $$f''(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^2}.$$
2. Suppose $f''(y)>0$ for all $y\in I$. Prove that f is concave up on I.

I tried to use the definition that $f$ is concave up if for all $t\in [0,1]$  $f(ta+(1-t)b)\leq tf(a)+(1-t)f(b).$

Let $a,b\in I$. By mean value theorem there exists $c\in (a,b)$, then we can write $c=ta+(1-t)b$ such that $$f''(c)=\frac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{b-a}.$$

Comment: What have you tried? What is the definition of concave up?

Comment: You must give the definition of 'concave up' you are using, as most people would refer to concave up for a double differentiable function to mean $f''(x) > 0$, in which case there is nothing to solve

Comment: I tried to use the definition that $f$ is concave up if for all $t\in [0,1]$  $f(ta+(1-t)b)\leq tf(a)+(1-t)f(b).$  I edited my question about how I tried to use also the MVT for the derivatives, but I couldn't conclude it.

Comment: Try finding $t$ such that $t\left(x+h\right) + \left(1-t\right)\left(x-h\right) = x$ and use the definition on the first part

Comment: Now, I got it, thank you!

Comment: Hint: Let $c = ta + (1-t)b$, we have: $$tf(a)+(1-t)f(b) - f(c)
= (1-t)(f(b) - f(c)) - t(f(c) - f(a))$$